# facebook and fbml

Tags: html, facebook, fbml

i am listing on the page into a select element the names of all friends of a user who uses my app.. the render is alright as below but then when it goes through fbml only one friend comes up?

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
                    <option value="" selected="true">Choose Friend</option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option>

                                            <option value="x"><fb:name uid="x" linked="FALSE"></option> (and so on....)

                    </select>
                    </form>
```

but then when it renders into the app all i get is one-

```
<option value="" selected="true">Choose Friend</option> 

<option value="x">John Smith</option></select>
```

(i have chanegd the values for privacy)

Answer (score 1):

```
</select>
```

In your code, i can see only above closing select tag but not the starting select tag. Add it in case you are missing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and including any appropriate classes and IDs would also be helpful.

I would also suggest that you look at the loop controlling how many are outputted, as it could be what is causing it.  Are you even including the  but it's just not showing up?  If so, you may want to increase the initial value of the loop.